# Regarding the Bolzano-Weierstrass proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have doubts regarding the Bolzano-Weierstrass proof My textbook proof same as
[Bolzano-Weierstrass proof explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3843235/842235) here my problem is why isn't it $n_1 \geq 1$? instead of  $n_1>1$

Can anyone give me a simple explanation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not so crucial that $n_1 > 1$, but the same idea is used later to make $n_{m+1} > n_m$, which *is* crucial.

The point is just that $I_1$ contains *infinitely many* terms of your sequence.  When you're picking $n_1$ you're asking for $x_{n_1} \in I_1$; it can't be the case that the only term of the sequence in $I_1$ is $x_1$, so we're free to ask for $n_1 > 1$.

A similar idea, but a bit more complicated, is what happens later in the proof: Because $I_{m+1}$ contains *infinitely many* terms of your sequence, the terms $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n_m}$ don't use up all of the terms of the sequence that are in $I_{m+1}$, so we can find $n_{m+1} > n_m$ such that $x_{n_{m+1}} \in I_{m+1}$.

Comment: you are saying it can't be the case that the only term of the sequence in $i_1$ is $x_1$ but$I_1$ contains infinitely many element so if $n_1 =1 \in I_1$ we can also choose it

Comment: Yes, we could choose $n_1 = 1$, if it happens that $x_1 \in I_1$, and there's nothing really wrong with doing so.  But the idea of why you *could* choose $n_1 > 1$ is important later in the proof.

Comment: I understood the later case   but how is it important to later case?

Comment: Because you're trying to build a subsequence, which means you need to choose indices $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$.

Comment: yes of course what's wrong $n_1=1$?